# What are some research articles on using principle components to generate alpha?

Tags: statistics, modeling, random-matrix-theory

Here's an example by Marco Avellenada from NYU titled "[Statistical Arbitrage in the U.S. Equities Market](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/AvellanedaLeeStatArb20090616.pdf)". The idea of this paper involves capturing mean reversion in the residual returns of a security after removing the principle components of return.

As another example, here is some research by Mark Kritzman showing how spikes in the "[absorption rate](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1633027)" are associated with drawdowns in the US equity market.

I wonder if there are other strategies involving the eigenportfolios or behavior of principal components other than the dominant eigenvector (i.e. the market portfolio) and non-random eigenvectors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attilio Meucci does some very interesting things with PCA. See e.g. his paper on managing diversification which makes heavy use of it (and explains it very intuitively along the way):

[Managing Diversification by Attilio Meucci](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1358533)

Comment: +1 Thanks - yep I'm a big fan of Meucci. This is on the risk side though, would be great to see research on the Alpha side

Comment: If you are a fan of Meucci, you have surely read this one http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1404905

Answer (score 4):

If you know R; here is a very good tutorial with practical examples:

http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/05.html

Comment: This is more of a tutorial on PCA rather than using PCA to generate alpha

Answer (score 2):

The Systematic Investor has a series of articles on using PCA and clustering to improve on traditional Risk Parity approaches.

The series of posts start here:
http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/visualizing-principal-components/